# Automate the Boring Stuff with Python: Nested Dictionaries and Lists

Tags: python, dictionary

The book contains an example of dictionary within a dictionary and I'm struggling to understand it.

*For example, here’s a program that uses a dictionary that contains other dictionaries in order to see who is bringing what to a picnic. The totalBrought() function can read this data structure and calculate the total number of an item being brought by all the guests.*

```
allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
             'Bob': {'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},
             'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}
def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
    return numBrought
print('Number of things being brought:')
print(' Apples    ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))
```

My question:
In *for k, v in guests.items()* what *guests.items()* stands for? If it stands for allGuests dictionary then what is *v*? The subdictionary ( dictionary within dictonary ) or it only represents numbers ( values within subdictionaries - 5, 12 etc. )? In other words is *k* 'Alice' and *v* {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12}?

Answer (score 1):

> In other words is k 'Alice' and v {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12}?

Yes.

`.items()` doesn't inspect the values it yields and break them up further if those values are dictionaries. More generally a dictionary (or list, set, tuple, etc.) doesn't know that it's nested and doesn't really care that much about its values. `allGuests` behaves just like any other dictionary.